# Questionable automated test in review

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

It is important that I make this clear from the beginning: This is not a complaint of any kind, but a suggestion to keep SO where it is.

I failed a test review of the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11234731). I voted to delete the answer as being a comment and got the "Stop and Look ..."  screen.

My judgment was based on the fact that the post starts by asking a yes/no
clarification about the question it is supposed to answer, then chooses an option and gives a recommendation based on that option. This first attempt is somehow deemed non appropriate and the answer is edited to also give some recommendations on the other direction.

When I look at the revision history of the post I can find this:

first attempt:

> Do you have this code in completion handler (I think so)?
>
> It is recommended that NSTimer be run in the main thread so this could be the reason.

This is clearly asking for clarification and should be posted as a comment
as recommended by SO.

added later (just a part of the edit)

> edit: No I do not have any doc. Only several stackoverflow posts and I`ve
> faced this issue by myself - it was only guess. Apple docs says:
> ...

Ultimately, by visiting the two alternative of the yes/no clarification, the post added enough information to be chosen as the accepted answer. However it remains clear to me that the post is more a comment unless I am a little bit to strict. I think that authors of such posts still need to learn that clarifications are asked in comments. And if the reviewers are failed because they flag such post, there is a problem.

If I actually voted any other option, I will clearly understand that my
judgement was wrong and my failure justified. I don't know if I am the first one to be tested with that example or not, but I think that this is a controversial test and as such can discourage SO reviewers. I would recommend to moderators/developers of SO to not use such tests.

Again, this is not a complaint, I have more to do than to be reviewing
or complaining on SO. My participation on SO is a simple way of giving back for the precious time I saved by getting the answer on some problems.

Comment: The second sentence of the first revision is "It is recommended that NSTimer be run in the main thread so this could be the reason." Regardless of the guesswork involved, that is an attempt at an answer. Maybe not a good one, maybe not a correct one, maybe an answer with a question attached. Still an answer, though - and moreso by the time it was edited.

Comment: @PaulRoub, thank you for your interest in the post. My concern was not the remove the fact that it is an answer. It is even the accepted one. Meaning the best one according to the OP. My concern is that using it as a metric is questionable, because it is subject to controversy. That is all what my point is about, and that is why I insisted that this is no a complaint, but only a suggestion, to be accepted or not.

Comment: This is *definitely* a bad answer, I can see how you would be tripped up. I'm not sure that "recommend deletion" was the right choice, but I certainly couldn't have clicked "looks OK".

Comment: @CodyGray In the LQP queue "looks okay" is *absolutely* the right call.  The answer doesn't merit deletion.  It's not a good answer, but it is *an answer*.  Of course, in the first/last post queue, where reviewers are expected to do more than just delete or not delete an answer, then doing nothing would indeed have been very wrong here, as this answer has lots of problems that could be either fixed with editing, pointed out in comments, voted on, etc.

Comment: @CodyGray I have edited the answer to make it looks more secure and assertive. I know that if I had the same review, I wouldn't have the heart to hit looks OK.

Comment: @Braiam Then you probably shouldn't be using the LQP queue.  The point of that queue is to delete content that isn't even an answer, not to improve answers that aren't good.  There are *several* other queues that exist for that purpose.

Comment: I've been caught by several of these.  A few are really borderline judgement calls, IMHO.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer There isn't anything borderline about this.  The answer doesn't merit deletion.  There are no grounds for it to be deleted.  It *is* an answer, even if you think it's a low quality one.

Comment: @Servy sorry, but there's a prominent "edit" button that begs for it. I try to edit whatever is salvageable and isn't included already. The best content stays, the repetition is removed. BTW, you can check my use of the LQRQ, is linked to my profile, if you have any doubts.

Comment: @Braiam You can edit such a post if you want, but as I said, voting to delete it is unquestionably not appropriate.

Comment: @Servy well, lets agree to disagree then. But this kind of behavior will just drown us in noise.

Comment: What good is a queue where the only options are "Looks OK" (a lie) and "Delete" (inappropriate in most cases)? I guess that's why I don't use these queues.

Comment: @CodyGray The queue is good for deleting posts that aren't actually answers, when those posts have been specifically flagged by users as being not answers.  Previously moderators had to evaluate all of those flags, and there were simply too many posts for them to keep up with them, and as a result many non-answers would either not get deleted, or they wouldn't get deleted for a very long time after being flagged.  If you want to do more than delete non-answers, there are *several* other queues that do other things.

Comment: @CodyGray You say that deletion is inappropriate in most cases, and yet in doing so you're showing your lack of experience with these queues.  Since the queue is fed by user flags of posts that merit deletion, it actually has a reasonably high percentage of posts meriting deletion being evaluated.  It's not like every single post goes in the queue.  The fact that you apparently do see a ton of non-answers is an attestment to the effectiveness of this queue at quickly deleting such answers.

Comment: @Braiam You're actively encouraging people to break the rules of the site and delete posts that don't merit deletion, because you just don't like it.  This isn't a subjective matter.  Whether or not a post merits deletion is based on rather strict guidelines.  The post very clearly does not meet any criteria for deletion.  People can agree to disagree over matters of opinion for which there is no objectively correct answer, such as whether or not the post is a *good* answer, or whether it should be upvoted/downvoted.  But as to whether or not it merits deletion is a matter of fact.

Comment: @Servy nah, is not. You and I know it. [And the help center too.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Braiam And what about that help center page does anything but confirm exactly what I've said?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the baggage carried from forums and problem guessing that SO sees every day. Next time, edit the post to at least make OP looks more assertive. This is a Q&A, so **everything has to adhere to the format of a Q&A**, be it that they are answers and that they look like answers.

Comment: Editing it is fine, but the fact remains that voting to delete it is simply wrong, as the audit correctly indicates.

Comment: @Servy if editing isn't possible, removing the answer is the *right* course of action. OP didn't considered that, because the queue is biased towards deletion (something by design). Is sad that those 5 upvoters didn't noticed the problem and fixed the answer, allowing it to become a potential corner case for reviewers that evaluate whenever or not it should be removed.

Comment: No, deletion is *entirely inappropriate*.  There is *no grounds* for deleting this post.  It's a valid answer, even if it's a low quality one.

Comment: @Servy who is saying that the answer should be deleted?

Comment: You did, "removing the answer is the right course of action."

Comment: @Servy you are misrepresenting my words, please when you quote someone, do not cherrypick phrases: **if editing isn't possible**, (juxtaposition) removing the answer is the right course of action. If true, then do.

Comment: Removing an answer like this is *never* the right course of action.  The answer doesn't merit deletion, so voting to delete it is *always* wrong.  If you want to edit it, you can, if you don't want to (and the reviewer is not obligated to), then the answer should be marked as being okay.

Comment: @Servy, since I reached the number of reputation to review, I reviewed few hundred of them, and I found two extreme situations another and this one. I did not report the first one, I think I should have done it. You will better understand why I said that this is not appropriate for review test. In the first one, the guy said a few things about the questions but clearly did not provide the right answer, did not ask for clarification, did not post anything abusive, was clearly not spamming. I voted it to be OK and failed the review too. Do you consider it appropriate to report this one?

Comment: @Servy then why isn't skip an option for you? Specially if you aren't prepared to edit the post if it merits edition.

Comment: @Braiam Why would I need to skip it?  The post doesn't merit deletion.  Indicating that ti doesn't merit deletion *is the correct response*.  You skip posts if you don't know what should happen, not if you know exactly what the correct response is.  You can edit the post if you want, but it doesn't need to be edited *to be an answer*.  Editing it isn't necessary for the post to stop meriting deletion, because it doesn't merit deletion from the start.

Comment: @innoSPG I couldn't possibly comment on the appropriateness of an audit without actually being able to see it.

Comment: @Servy, I know that you did not see it. I do not know how to pull it and give you the link. If you know how I can do that, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really think that posting a rhetorical question an answer makes it not an answer?

Sorry, but no.  The post is not inherently seeking information without providing an answer.  *That* would be something that would belong in a comment.  This answer is essentially posting an assertion, phrased as a question, and posting **an answer to the question** based on that assertion.

You could certainly argue that it's not a good answer, either because the assertion isn't merited, or that it's not providing enough information, or whatever, I don't know enough about the subject to evaluate such critiques (although it doesn't look like a good answer to me) so I wouldn't vote on it.  If you do feel that it's not a good answer, feel free to downvote it.

But *it is an answer*, and doesn't merit deletion.  The fact that the post contains a question mark in it doesn't change that.

Honestly, this a pretty good audit for this reason.  Someone sees what is grammatically a question, and thus votes to delete *an answer* based solely on the fact that it contains a question mark at the start of it, despite the fact that the post is pretty clearly *attempting to answer the question* when reading past the first half of the first sentence.  You weren't reading closely, and as a result *made the wrong call*; the audit caught you on it.

Comment: I've never been convinced that SO is the place to emulate forum threads filled with "well, if it's this, try that, but otherwise let me know and we'll work out some more". An answer that starts off guessing at one possible problem is usually either a sign that more commenting needs to be done to fix the *question*, or an over-cautious *answer* that can have the guesswork trimmed to be more authoritative (if it's actually the correct guess almost all of the time). Getting hung up on the "rhetorical" question is, in turn, a red herring.

Comment: @NathanTuggy That's asserting that it's a *bad answer*, not that it isn't an answer at all.  If you don't think that it's appropriate for someone to guess at what the problem is, downvote it.  Voting to delete it however is simply wrong.

Comment: An answer that is just shotgunned onto the question does not deserve any particular protection from deletion. If it's a reasonable guess, it needs to be edited to remove the noise of guessing. If it's unreasonable, it needs to be deleted for the same reason. Normally, I hate deleting answers with any sign of salvage-ability, but I've seen far too many questions that descend into useless forum threads discussing all the possible permutations of some vague problem description.

Comment: @NathanTuggy If you don't like the fact that it's a guess **then downvote it**.  That is the appropriate mechanism to indicate that you don't like the answer.   Answers don't merit deletion for being a guess, any more than they merit deletion for being wrong.  Editing the answer to remove the stated assertion *harms* the answer.  The stated assertion means that a reader of that answer will be able to tell whether or not it applies to them; removing it is removing relevant information from that answer.

Comment: An answer that does not reliably apply to the question is really an answer that contains part of the question itself. That's not SO, that's a forum. Whether that should be deleted, edited to move the question part into the question, or what, depends on the individual situation. Proclaiming this as a shining example of audit reliability and precision is unreasonable, though. It's just not very good. Hard cases make bad law, and the fact that competent, experienced, dedicated reviewers disagree makes this a bad audit indeed. (It's obvious, though, that "Edit" would pass everyone's smell test.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy You can have an answer that is unquestionably just flat wrong.  It won't apply to a question *ever*.  That doesn't mean you delete it.  It means you downvote it.  The answer is a clear attempt to answer the question.  If you think it's a failed attempt, you downvote it.  There are no grounds for deleting it at all.  It doesn't depend on the situation.  An answer that you think is based on a false assumption is still an answer.  You also don't edit answers into questions.  They're answers.

Comment: The fact that dedicated reviewers are trying to delete a post that *unquestionably meets no criteria for deletion* just because it's a bad answer is highly concerning, far more so than an audit.  It's been a very fundamental principle of the site that answers are voted on based on their quality, and only deleted when they *aren't answers at all*.  If you don't think the answer is a good answer, that's fine, I don't think it's a good answer either, but you need to reflect that opinion appropriately.

Comment: Basically, I believe an answer that is on the wrong question should be deleted. If you disagree, that's fine; proclaiming one-true-wayism and how concerning it is that other users don't get how important it is to preserve answers posted on the wrong question is, however, quite excessive. We understand very well, thank you, and the importance is pretty slim.

Comment: And an answer to a "wildcard" question, one that should be closed until it's edited, and that clearly shows *why* we close such questions... why are you trying to defend that as any different? It's not a useful question/answer pair; the answer has borrowed part of the question's role. To the extent that the answer is saying "if your question is X", it's trying to be a forum post, or part of the question. That needs to be fixed one way or another. Answers are to *answer the question*, not to bring up different question branches.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I'm not saying that this is a quality answer.  I'm saying that it is *an answer*.  If you think the answer isn't useful **downvote it**.  That's literally *exactly what that feature is there for*.  The fact that you believe an answer that's wrong should be deleted **is irrelevant** because the rules of the site specifically state when it is and is not appropriate to delete an answer, and this post does not meet the criteria for deletion; the fact that you want it to be deleted is irrelevant.

Comment: I think that I did not made clear that "I do not question the fact that the post was an answer". The point and @NathanTuggy got it is that it is not a good ground for review test.

Comment: The ground for deletion was not that the answer was bad quality. It is an answer asking for clarification, and there is ground for voting to delete those answers as being more of a comment than answer.

Comment: @innoSPG No, that's simply not true.  The answer is *not* asking for clarification.  It's posting a solution to the problem.  It is not posted simply to seek information from the question author.  It is *providing a solution*.  That it began with a rhetorical question to state an assertion that the solution is based off of make it *look* like a request for clarification, if you didn't read past the first half of the first sentence, but when reading it carefully it's clear that that's not the case.

Comment: @innoSPG Why isn't it a good review test?  It's an appropriate answer that shouldn't be deleted.  Voting to delete it is *wrong*, and indicates that the reviewer isn't paying close enough attention.  That makes it a great audit.

Comment: @Servy, something need to be clarify again. By saying only "voting to be deleted", you are actually taking only one part of my concern. A question can can be voted for deletion for many reasons. I clearly stated that if I chose any other option apart from being more of a comment, I agree that the judgement was wrong. Now if you do not want to consider that part, it is up to you. And you have the freedom to take it the way you want.

Comment: @innoSPG Yes, you said that you voted to delete the post because you think that it's a comment, and not an answer.  **That is wrong.  The post is an answer, and should not have been a comment instead**.  What about that isn't clear from my answer?

Comment: @Servy, Do you mean the option for voting an answer as being a comment is a wrong option? Up to now, I find it to be clear that if you need clarification, you post a comment. And the guys needed a clarification but did not ask for clarification. Instead, he asked it in his answer, guessed the answer and got it wrong in the first attempt. Then later try the other path. What is not clear about that?

Comment: I am not sure if you understood my concern. I am not complaining of anything. I am not even saying that it was not an answer. It was just a mean to raise the concern. You have the right to not like it. You do not have any obligation to reply.

Comment: @innoSPG If you know that the post isn't an answer and shouldn't be deleted, then why did you vote to delete it?  Why are you coming to meta and claiming that the audit is wrong if you know that you were wrong to vote to delete it?  Why are you claiming in earlier comments to this post that the answer merits deletion, if you know that the answer doesn't merit deletion?

Comment: @Servy, please can you look back and tell me where I said that the audit was wrong? Please read my post again! I expressed a suggestion because SO is opened to suggestions. It is possible that you are debating where there is not need for debating!

Comment: @innoSPG "However it remains clear to me that the post is more a comment unless I am a little bit to strict. I think that authors of such posts still need to learn that clarifications are asked in comments. And if the reviewers are failed because they flag such post, there is a problem."  You're claiming that the post is a comment, and thus merits deletion, despite the fact that the audit says it should not be.  The post shouldn't be a comment, and doesn't merit deletion (by your own admission now?)

Comment: @Servy! did you read this other part of my post? "I think that this is a controversial test and as such can discourage SO reviewers. I would recommend to moderators/developers of SO to not use such tests." Do you make a difference between asserting that the audit is wrong and what I am saying?

Comment: @Servy, after few years without reviewing anything on SO, I had some free time and thought about it; then I remember this long chat with you and I came back to read it. I really appreciate you for testing my limits of keeping the conversation cool, it was quite challenging to keep it that cool. How are you doing? Still patrolling SO? Unfortunately, taking the time to reread this thread did not leave me anymore time to review anything, but I will be back.